# get each datagridview row wise controls using c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

i am trying to get controls in datagridview each row wise,here i web application Ok but same as i want in windows form using c#.
    advance thaqs.

**web application code**

```
       foreach (Control c in gridview.Rows[i].Controls)
        {
       if (c.NamingContainer.GetType() == typeof(GridViewRow))
        {
        foreach (Control cc in c.Controls)
           {
        ....
        }
```

**windows application code**

```
 foreach (Control c in gridview.gridView.Rows[i].Controls)// iam getting error
    {
   if (c.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewRow))
   {
  foreach (Control cc in c.Controls)
   {...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Private Sub sub_Form_Validators(ByVal f As Object)
        'For Loop for Getting all Fields in the Given form using control option
        For Each obj As Object In CType(f, Control).Controls
            If TypeOf obj Is TextBox Then
                'For Text Box
                Dim txt As TextBox = obj
                txt.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                txt.ForeColor = Color.Black 'Color.FromName(forecolor)
                txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                AddHandler txt.EnabledChanged, AddressOf sub_textbox_EnabledChanged
                AddHandler txt.GotFocus, AddressOf sub_Textbox_GotFocus_Validator
                AddHandler txt.LostFocus, AddressOf sub_Textbox_LostFocus_Validator
            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is RichTextBox Then
                Dim txt As RichTextBox = obj
                txt.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                txt.ForeColor = Color.Black 'Color.FromName(forecolor)
                AddHandler txt.EnabledChanged, AddressOf sub_RichTextBox_EnabledChanged
                AddHandler txt.GotFocus, AddressOf sub_RichTextBox_GotFocus_Validator
                AddHandler txt.LostFocus, AddressOf sub_RichTextBox_LostFocus_Validator
            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is TabControl Then            'For Tab Control
                Dim tab As TabControl = obj
                tab.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor) 'backcolor
                sub_Form_Validators(obj)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is TabPage Then               'For Tab Page
                Dim tabpage As TabPage = obj
                tabpage.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                tabpage.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                sub_Form_Validators(obj)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is RadioButton Then           'For Radio Button
                Dim rbtn As RadioButton = obj
                rbtn.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                rbtn.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                rbtn.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is CheckBox Then              'For Check Box
                Dim chk As CheckBox = obj
                chk.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                chk.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                chk.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is ComboBox Then              'For Combo box
                Dim cmb As ComboBox = obj
                'cmb.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                cmb.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                AddHandler cmb.EnabledChanged, AddressOf cmb_EnabledChanged
                AddHandler cmb.GotFocus, AddressOf Combobox_GotFocus_Validator
                AddHandler cmb.LostFocus, AddressOf Combobox_LostFocus_Validator
                cmb.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is Button Then                'For Button
                Dim btn As Button = obj

                    'btn.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor) ' backcolor 'Color.FromArgb(frmButtonColorRed, frmButtonColorGreen, frmButtonColorBlue)
                    btn.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                    'btn.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.White

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is DataGridView Then          'For Grid view
                Dim gridview As DataGridView = obj
                gridview.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                gridview.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                gridview.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                gridview.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                'gridview.BackgroundColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                gridview.BackgroundColor = Color.White
                gridview.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Raised
                gridview.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Sunken
                gridview.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is ToolStrip Then             'For Toolstrip
                Dim tstrip As ToolStrip = obj
                tstrip.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                tstrip.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                tstrip.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is ToolStripButton Then       'For Toolstrip Button
                Dim tbtn As ToolStripButton = obj
                tbtn.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                tbtn.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                tbtn.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is Panel Then                 'For Panel
                Dim pnl As Panel = obj
                pnl.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                pnl.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                pnl.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                sub_Form_Validators(obj)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is GroupBox Then              'For Group Box
                Dim grp As GroupBox = obj
                grp.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                grp.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)
                grp.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)

            ElseIf TypeOf obj Is Label Then                 'For Label
                Dim lbl As Label = obj
                lbl.BackColor = Color.FromName(backcolor)
                lbl.Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize, fs_fontstyle)
                lbl.ForeColor = Color.FromName(forecolor)

            Else
                sub_Form_Validators(obj)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```